# Robot Framework - unable to locate React created elements

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to Input Text into a React created element. So far I have tried the following methods:

```
Input Text     css:input#textfield-1198-inputEl    TEXT
Input Text     css:input.x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-#textfield-1198-inputEl   TEXT
Input Text      xpath=//input[contains(@name,'textfield-1198-inputEl')]   TEXT
Input Text     xpath=//*[@id="textfield-1198-inputEl"]   TEXT
```

As well as trying the absolute & relative paths, though it always responds with - did not match any elements.
Wait Until Element Is Visible times out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="x-window x-layer x-window-default x-closable x-window-closable x-window-default-closable x-border-box x-resizable x-window-resizable x-window-default-resizable" id="window-1196" style="width: 316px; height: 195px; right: auto; left: 630px; top: 315px; z-index: 19001;" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="x-window-header x-header x-header-horizontal x-header-draggable x-docked x-unselectable x-window-header-default x-horizontal x-window-header-horizontal x-window-header-default-horizontal x-top x-window-header-top x-window-header-default-top x-docked-top x-window-header-docked-top x-window-header-default-docked-top" id="window-1196_header" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 316px;">
            <div class="x-header-body x-window-header-body x-window-header-body-default x-window-header-body-horizontal x-window-header-body-default-horizontal x-window-header-body-top x-window-header-body-default-top x-window-header-body-docked-top x-window-header-body-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-window-header-body-default-horizontal x-window-header-body-default-top x-window-header-body-default-docked-top" id="window-1196_header-body" style="width: 309px;">
                <div class="x-box-inner" id="window-1196_header-innerCt" role="presentation" style="width: 309px; height: 15px;">
                    <div class="x-box-target" id="window-1196_header-targetEl" style="width: 309px;">
                        <div class="x-component x-header-text-container x-window-header-text-container x-window-header-text-container-default x-box-item x-component-default" id="window-1196_header_hd" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 288px;">
                            <span class="x-header-text x-window-header-text x-window-header-text-default" id="window-1196_header_hd-textEl">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="x-tool x-box-item x-tool-default x-tool-after-title" id="tool-1203" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; right: auto; left: 294px; top: 0px; margin: 0px;"><img class="x-tool-img x-tool-close" id="tool-1203-toolEl" role="presentation" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="x-window-body x-window-body-default x-closable x-window-body-closable x-window-body-default-closable x-window-body-default x-window-body-default-closable x-resizable x-window-body-resizable x-window-body-default-resizable" id="window-1196-body" style="overflow: auto; left: 0px; width: 316px; height: 165px; top: 30px;">
            <span id="window-1196-outerCt" style="display:table;"></span>
            <div class="" id="window-1196-innerCt" style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; display: table-cell;">
                <span id="window-1196-outerCt" style="display:table;"></span>
                <div class="x-panel x-window-item x-panel-default" id="createCMDBPanel-1197" style="width: 316px; height: 165px;">
                    <span id="window-1196-outerCt" style="display:table;"></span>
                    <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-default x-panel-body-default x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-bottom x-docked-noborder-left" id="createCMDBPanel-1197-body" style="padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 316px; height: 125px;">
                        <span id="window-1196-outerCt" style="display:table;"><span id="createCMDBPanel-1197-outerCt" style="display:table;"></span></span>
                        <div class="" id="createCMDBPanel-1197-innerCt" style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; display: table-cell;">
                            <span id="window-1196-outerCt" style="display:table;"></span>
                            <table cellpadding="0" class="x-field x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-text x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" id="textfield-1198" style="table-layout: auto;">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="x-form-item-input-row" id="textfield-1198-inputRow" role="presentation">
                                        <td class="x-field-label-cell" id="textfield-1198-labelCell" role="presentation" style="" valign="top" width="105"><label class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-left" for="textfield-1198-inputEl" id="textfield-1198-labelEl" style="width:100px;margin-right:5px;">CMDB Name:</label></td>
                                        <td class="x-form-item-body" colspan="2" id="textfield-1198-bodyEl" role="presentation"><input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text" data-errorqtip="" id="textfield-1198-inputEl" name="textfield-1198-inputEl" type="text" value="new CMDB"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that the actual error message? Be as precise as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the attribute values React puts are "semi-dynamic" (my term, and don't quote me on it :) - they are generated by the framework as it sees fit, and can change on slight source code change. This applies for the `class` and in your case for the `id` attribute - as you can see the number 1198 in it has no semantic meaning, it's just a counter.
Thus you'd better not use them in locators, as they won't be rigid - the value can easily change between builds without warning.

I would approach it with a different strategy; here is an xpath locator that works, breakdown of its structure follows:

```
//td[label[text()="CMDB Name:"]]/following-sibling::td/input[@type="text"]
```

It first selects a table cell that has as its child `span` with that text - the label the user sees in the UI for the input. Then it selects the very next cell (the `following-sibling` axis), and finally - the `input` element that is *its* child - your target.

In effect, this locator reads - "return the input that is next to the text 'CMDB Name:'"

Comment: Hi, @Todor!
So, with current React approach, all the advantages we had thanks to classed, ids and DOM traversing are...
Gone?
We're back to parsing text? That is quite bad news :(

Comment: I wouldn't say it's that bad; ids can be fixed, plus development can always set a custom element attribute with a predefined value to be used for locators. Classes - they are off limits (but that has always been the case, at least for == comparisons).

Comment: Handy Tip:  Install Selenium IDE,  and record actions. After opening the project file it is possible to  : Input Text       xpath=//span/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input       ...project options =  "targets": [
        ["id=textfield-1198-inputEl", "id"],
        ["name=textfield-1198-inputEl", "name"],
        ["css=#textfield-1198-inputEl", "css"],
        ["xpath=//input[@id='textfield-1198-inputEl']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//td[@id='textfield-1198-bodyEl']/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//span/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input", "xpath:position"]
      ],